# Encrypt joomla admin login password

Tags: joomla2.5, password-encryption

I want to encrypt Joomla 2.5.22 admin login password to be encrypted, so that it can not travel in the network in the plain text. I have checked using Burp Suite the login password appear in plain text, i want it to be encrypted. Can you please suggest solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this.

1. Change your website to use SSL.
2. Install a third party extension like the free "Encrypt configuration" http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/11519 or look for something similar in the "Login protection" category in the Joomla Extensions Directory: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection